# What does RESUME opcode actually do?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-RESUME) is not very informative (at least for me):

> opcode:: RESUME (context)
>
> A no-op. Performs internal tracing, debugging and optimization
> checks.
>
> The `context` oparand consists of two parts. The lowest two bits
> indicate where the `RESUME` occurs:
>
> - `0` The start of a function, which is neither a generator,
>   coroutine
>   nor an async generator
> - `1` After a `yield` expression
> - `2` After a `yield from` expression
> - `3` After an `await` expression
>
> The next bit is `1` if the RESUME is at except-depth `1`, and
> `0`    otherwise.

Example:

```py
>>> import dis
>>> 
>>> def f(): ...
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 RESUME                   0
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Can someone provide an explanation of what this opcode really does?

Comment: @AdesojiAlu Thanks for your response, but I couldn't find anything useful related to my question in the link.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. What exactly do you need to know about it? How are we supposed to know what's "useful" to you?

Comment: @Barmar I want to know what does the interpreter do when it reaches `RESUME` opcode.

Comment: It updates some internal bookkeeping data.